# What is the connection between the words "ambitious and "it" in this text?

Tags: word-meaning

> I am an easy going and laid back person, I love life and try to live to the fullest. One of my favorite activities is to smile and make people laugh, I feel there is so much negativity being projected into our lives that I want to bring happiness and light. There is so much that this life has to offer and I have chosen to be happy in it and be grateful for all the blessings that have been bestowed upon me. I lead my own experience and don't follow trends and/or people. I am an **ambitious** person and I believe I can have **it** all love, family, friendship and a career and I want someone who shares that same view and who encourages my success, as will I with them and not be intimidated by it.

What if we remove the word **it** ? 
...I can have all life, family, friendship and a career...  this seems to be awkward, doesn't it? 
...I can have **it** all love, family, friendship and a career...   this seems better, but I can not understand the use and meaning of thd word **it** .

Answer (score 2):

The original usage is slightly incorrect. They should have used a colon:

> I can have it all: life, family, friendship and a career.

With the colon, it is clear that "it" is necessary. Without it, the transitive verb "have" is missing a direct object.

It would be more normal to use "have all of it", except that "it all" here is a somewhat idiomatic construction meaning "everything I consider valuable". It is followed by a list of what the speaker considers valuable.

The phrase "have it all" was popularized in the US in the 1980s, when it came to refer having a good job and a good family and succeeding in and enjoying both. Until that time, men were taught that they had to sacrifice time with their families to work harder and provide for the family financially, and women were taught that they had to give up on work in order to care for the family more directly. "Have it all" is shorthand for doing both: having a successful career and a happy family, with the subtext that this is considered difficult, and possibly even foolish or impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's the expression "have it all", not "all love":

> (I can have it all): (love, family, friendship and a career.....)

And frankly, I'd expect a colon, which I included for better readability.

There. is no connection whatsoever between "ambitious" and "it", it's *I'm an ambitious person* and *I believe* that are semantically on the same level.